# What is a 'crab', and how does one perform/obtain one?

Tags: team-fortress-2, terminology, tf2-spy

Ok, so there I was playing TF2, as a Spy (and doing quite well, at least by my low standards). When the other team begins with the usual friendly greetings, racial/sexual orientation slurs, as well as wondering how my mother was doing (so kind of them), when suddenly somebody bets me that I "can't even crab"

Of course, my interest was piqued, and I inquired as to the origins of this phrase, and was deluged with calls of 'noob', with no real answer.

So, what is a crab? Is it a wearable/unlockable or some sort of tactic/manoeuver?

Comment: Spy, do you even crab?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The person was referring to crab walking (or doing the Spycrab), which is a set of movements you may perform that are [amusing in the 3rd person perspective](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bTIIKlaFunk) (but not as much in 1st person).

To perform the Spycrab, equip your Disguise Kit, crouch, and look upward. Walking around will make you look like a crab.

More recently, as an acknowledgement of this community phenomenon, the Disguise Kit was given a second taunt that performs a Spycrab, which may have been what the person was talking about. This taunt is performed at a reduced chance (empirically, it appears to be about 20-25%).

The random nature of this taunt has lead to the creation of a gambling game often played on trade servers, where participants pay some amount of metal, then repeatedly taunt with the Disguise Kit until they Spycrab. The last remaining player who has not Spycrabbed wins the pot.

Comment: For best results, don't walk forward like the spy in that video - strafe sideways like a real crab.